# Tmuxconf is disabled but I write in right place right lint

Tags: tmux

I made ~/.tmux.conf

this, and restarted tmux and terminal

but keybind is still `<c-b>`.

Why does this happen?

```
# C-bのキーバインドを解除
unbind C-b
# prefixキーをC-qに変更
set -g prefix C-q

# vimのキーバインドでペインを移動する
bind h select-pane -L
bind j select-pane -D
bind k select-pane -U
bind l select-pane -R

# ステータスバーの色を設定する
set -g status-fg white
set -g status-bg black

# コピーモードを設定する
## viのキーバインドを使用
setw -g mode-keys vi
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In .bashrc, adding `tmux source-file ~/.tmux.conf`
solved the problem. 
and `q` key is used somewhere so I needed to type ctrl shift q 
to use as tmux prefix. I changed this to `w`.
Then ctrl w worked as tmux prefix perfectly.